# Get request error in resting framework

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I am creating an android client which connects to the web service and gets a response code. The problem is the android app crashes whenever I run the following code:

```
 RequestParams params = new BasicRequestParams(); 
 params.add("client_id", "24f8b46fc9db409012830ca264ad7bcf");
 params.add("response_type", "code");

 ServiceResponse response=Resting.get("http://pricewatch.ap01.aws.af.cm/api/pricewatch/oAuth/auth",80,params);

 IContentData contentData = response.getContentData();
 String content = (String) contentData.getContent();

 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
 String code = (String) jsonObject.get("code");
 return code;
```

It generates a java.lang.NullPointerException with these line:

```
  IContentData contentData = response.getContentData();
```

Could someone help with these? I've been stuck with these. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you checked the value of `reponse` var?

Comment: Also i tried to implement it in restlet framework same response. I switched to resting framework. The code you see is implemented in resting framework

Comment: I run this code in a java application. It worked and the response var returns a json format plus the response headers.

Comment: @Vishal the debugger says that the response value returns a null

Comment: have you given the uses permission - `android.permission.INTERNET`?

Comment: @Vishal yes. I did that.

Comment: I had the same issue. It solved after i added android.permission.INTERNET in manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run this code many times in the emulator but never worked. However, when I run this in an android device it worked! NullPointerException happens when it doesn't get anything or any response in the server. But what I don't understand is why does this happen? Is there a difference between an emulator and an android device in terms of executing an android application?

Comment: No there is no any difference between an emulator & android device in terms of executing an android application as far as your question is concerned.The reason you were getting NPE is because your emulator was not able to access the internet & the reason it was not able to access internet is you are not setting dns server settings in launch configuration.You can set them under Windows->Preferences->Android->Launch, Now under default emulator options put-> `-dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`